# How to made masonry like in example?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

i need to make items on my site in masonry view, but masonry dosent work as well for me, i found this CSS method to do what i need -
http://jsfiddle.net/L6tf7u3b/1/
Buy element in this case go vertical (you will see in example), and i need way like this -

```
1|2
3|4
5|6
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4744mmrp/1/ this work fine for me and look like i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in previous code, some media queries allowed

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
```

**Example 1:**
http://jsfiddle.net/L6tf7u3b/2/

I've removed the code where allowed column-count 3 and 5, so now for all screen sizes above 400px, it will only have 2 columns

**Example 2:** Just saw your comment, a new example using Flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/ppcuh283/

a good guide to Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**Example 3:** An example using Masonry and jQuery
http://jsfiddle.net/ppcuh283/2/

Comment: I need view in this direction - 1,2
And i have - 1
2
3 - in vertical direction, and i need horizontal.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ppcuh283/1/ - blocks dont change their position and go on line with highest block, dosent look like masonry.

Comment: @user2486902 check my example 3 link again, i may have linked a wrong one